# How to add git commit information details in a declarative jenkins email notification post action?

Tags: git, jenkins

I currently have this post action to let me know via email that the jenkins build was successful:

```
post {
            always {
            emailext body: "${env.SITE} was deployed to ${DEPLOY_TO} with the following results: ${currentBuild.currentResult} ", subject: "Deployment results for ${env.SITE}", to: 'user@host.com,user2@host.com'
                    }
            }
}
```

The build is triggered once there's a new commit into the repository, so I would like to know how to include the commit hash, commit message and perhaps the commit diff for all the lines that were changed. I really don't know how detailed I can get in the email. I haven't found anything that can get me started on this online. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try using a groovy template for your body to be included? `https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates`
It can email the needs you have. Include it via `body: '${SCRIPT,template="yourfile.template"}'`. If you're having trouble I can provide a more detailed scripted pipeline example.

Comment: @Unforgettable631 Thank you for your response, I was looking mostly for a Groovy syntax so I could just add it to the code I already have and not add a template like I would have to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [last changes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/last-changes) for that, once the plugin is installed you can use the following pipeline snippet to send an e-mail with the diff:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('send html diff') {
            steps {
                git 'https://github.com/YOUR_REPO.git'
                script {
                  def publisher = LastChanges.getLastChangesPublisher "PREVIOUS_REVISION", "SIDE", "LINE", true, true, "", "", "", "", ""
                  publisher.publishLastChanges()
                  def htmlDiff = publisher.getHtmlDiff()
                  writeFile file: 'build-diff.html', text: htmlDiff
                    emailext (
                      subject: "Jenkins - changes of ${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}",
                      attachmentsPattern: '**/*build-diff.html',
                      mimeType: 'text/html',
                      body: """<p>See attached diff of build <b>${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</b>.</p>
                        <p>Check build changes on Jenkins <b><a href="${env.BUILD_URL}/last-changes">here</a></b>.</p>""",
                      to: "YOUR-EMAIL@gmail.com" )
                } //end script
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a section about sending the diff as e-mail on [plugin docs here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Last+Changes+Plugin#LastChangesPlugin-Sendingthediffasemail).

Comment: Thank you @rmpestano I was just wondering if I could just use some of what I already have and add it to the post build step.